# Angular $watchCollection callback not capturing changes in object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using three input checkboxes with the ngModel directive to bind to properties of an object called 'props'.

I'm using $scope.$watchCollection to set up a watch on all the properties of 'props' (there are three).

In my $watchCollection callback function, I need to compare the old property values to the new ones, but within the function, the old and new properties are always the same!

Here's a working example: http://jsbin.com/eYofakU/3/edit. What's going on here?

This uses Angular 1.2.0-rc.3

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This works for me. I changed the `$watchCollection` to `$watch` and set the 3rd parameter to true which tells angular to create a deep copy of the object being watched for comparison:

```
$scope.$watch("props",function(n,o){
    console.log("NEW");
    console.log(n);
    console.log("OLD");
    console.log(o);
    console.log("Why are they the same?!");
},true);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Edit** This is i[ssue has been closed](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621), it should work now since version 1.2.15.

-- old answer --
There is [an issue still open with $watchCollection](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621) , your options are to use @CodeHater  solution or try the [quick fix proposed by johnsoftek on github](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2621#issuecomment-23101337), (you'll need to build angular js file)

**Edit**: I tried the quick fix reported on github, and it seems to work, this is your example working in a plnkr.co http://plnkr.co/s9W2B84sX8lZOOUgifEL
Notice that the angular version is v1.2.5-ca116c3 as I built it today (Dec 8) from the master branch.
**Edit**:13/01/14
the issue is part of Milestone: 1.2.9